# EOL Notice: Vivid Vervet (15.04) is now EOL as of February 4, 2016

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that have reached End of Life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives are **officially end of life** as of February 4, 2016:

- Vivid Vervet (15.04).

New questions regarding the above posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**. Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed on the **[official Ubuntu Wiki page that lists all current, development, and end-of-lifed releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)**, and on the **[15.04 End of Life Announcement email message stating the official End Of Life date](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-January/000203.html)**, establishing February 4th as the EOL date.

Please upgrade to a supported release. If you don't like upgrading it is highly recommended you install a [long term support release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) in the future.

---

> NOTE: This does not currently impact Ubuntu Phone, which has an Overlay PPA which will be used after the standard Vivid repository closes, to it up to date. Questions ***specific to Ubuntu Touch and Ubuntu Phones which are running Vivid*** will remain on topic until such later time that this changes

---

> This Meta thread is NOT a discussion of how we handle EOL releases. This is simply a notification to all about an upcoming "End of Life" date for a current release of Ubuntu (as of this posting being made). Please refrain from asking in comments about how we handle EOL questions, or commenting on such handling policies.

Comment: The FAQ should be edited to include the exception for Ubuntu phone ( http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic ). That URL is used most to point people to read up on the "rules" of AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind I disagree because this will change once Xenial is available as I understood what I was told by the Ubuntu Touch people

Comment: I love the last paragraph... experience right?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.04 ("trusty") but I am using a kernel 3.19.0-33-generic which comes from vivid.

Does vivid's EOL mean this kernel version will also stop receiving updates?

Comment: @joeytwiddle The *kernel packages in Trusty* from newer releases fall under Trusty, not those releases (for instance, `linux-generic-lts-utopic` still gets security fixes in Trusty, but Utopic is EOL).  (Security team will still provide updates to that kernel in Trusty, only, as I understand it)

Comment: @muru  True.  Though, tomorrow morning I am doing a revision of the post anyways since it EOLs

Comment: @ThomasW.  Now that you're mentioning Utopic as being EOL, this too got me today! I was wondering why I couldn't reinstall that one and only 3.x kernel I wanted to keep in `grub`. Gave me some ugly 404's first, and I went like...WTF?! Until a vast (!) Google search finally gave me the idea that I had to add *old-releases.ubuntu.com* to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Why didn't anyone tell me earlier...? ;) So I'm not too happy about the idea that __entire__ Ubuntu releases get __removed__ from public repositories. They've radically skipped from trusty to vivid, as if utopic had never existed.

Comment: @syntaxerror if I'm not mistaken the removal isn't immediate.

Comment: @Braiam removal is whenever they remove it - so therefore, it could be today, or it could be tomorrow.

Comment: @syntaxerror if you don't like the way it's handled, I invite you to contact the archive maintainers and such, because they're the ones who determined this.  It's also sane to remove it from the standard repositories if you want to discourage people using security-hole-riddled OSes.

Comment: Well, I can criticize and accept facts as they are at the same time, can't I? I do dislike it, that's true; but yet I think there are many more important things going on which are actually worth an *active fight* against, for instance, buy-outs  by huge corporations. :] (e. g. by showing some "resistance" by ditching MySQL and using MariaDB instead (coded by the *original* MySQL programmer))

Comment: @syntaxerror this isn't the place for such arguments or voicing of opinions, though.  Yes, you can criticize, no, this isn't the place for it.

Comment: @ThomasW. I know, I know. Not intending to extend this any further, no worries. I think I was just tempted stating something because from your tone, *you* sounded as if directly involved in Ubuntu team's discussions and/or decisions, like a kind of team representative or spokesperson. :) Looks I was wrong.

Comment: My birthday, and a ubuntu thingy died.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of February 4, 2016, Vivid Vervet 15.04 is now End of Life.

New questions regarding Vivid, with the exception of the items listed below, are now offtopic.

The following are exceptions to this:

- Ubuntu Touch Vivid - There is an Overlay PPA that will provide updates for Ubuntu Touch until Xenial 16.04's release.
- Ubuntu Vivid Kernel in Trusty (`linux-generic-lts-vivid`) - This is an ***independent Trusty package in the repositories***, and is NOT offtopic as it is Trusty and not Vivid.

Comment: AFAIK Snappy vivid is still on-topic too.. This is getting more and more messy D:

Answer (score 18):

Note that Ubuntu Phone devices are still running on a Vivid derivative, and will likely continue to do so until the details of the GCC 5 migration are settled.

So questions related to those devices or development of apps for those devices should still be considered on topic despite the end of life notice.

Comment: Incorporated this into the original post

Comment: Do you know about snappy? Last I checked a few weeks ago the latest download was still 15.04.

Comment: @Seth that's a question for ubuntu-devel or ubuntu-release, I don't know specifically.\